# Implode and print_r

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print an array the way that print_r is printing it without the tags as a string

For example:

If I have an array:

```
array (
  0 => 'doh',
  1 => 'ray',
  2 => 'me',
  3 =>
  array (
    0 => 'fah',
    1 => 'soh',
    2 => 'lah',
    3 => 'te',
    4 => 'do',
  ),
)
```

I want to print a string with "doh ray me fah soh lah te do" (All array elements).

I tried implode() but its only returning "doh ray me"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$results = array();

array_walk_recursive(
    $your_array,
    function ($value, $key) use (&$results) {
        $results[] = $value;
    });

echo implode(' ', $results);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function custom_implode($arr, $str) {
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        if(is_array($val) {
            $str .= ' '.custom_implode($val, $str);
        }
        else {
            $str .= ' '.$val;
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy... just use

```
<pre> 
 <?php print_r($an_array); ?> 
</pre>
```

Boom, You are done.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that where you have more control

```
foreach ($arrayname as $str)
    echo $str." ";
```